# Why always two cotton wick used in deepa(Lamp)?

Tags: worship

In my region(south canara) we always use 2 cotton wick for lighting lamp.

How many cotton wick should be used in lamp ? Is it always two or can we use any number of cotton wicks?

Comment: It depends upon the tradition that is being followed in your place.  One astrologer said that if 3wicks are used, it will be good as Lakshmi, Parvati and Saraswati will be appeased.:-)@Karthik